# (half-of a) hairy ball theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

so I know that, by the hairy ball theorem, there does not exist a smooth global frame for the n-sphere.

What about for the northern hemisphere? Can anyone comb half-of a sphere (provide a smooth global frame)?

Comment: use stereographic projection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. The northern hemisphere of $S^n$ is diffeomorphic to the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, so it does admit a non-vanishing vector field, namely take the pushforward of the vector field $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Wait, so they form a basis at each point that smoothly varies?